# Запись текста в файл с сохранением форматирования

Tags: c#

Как записать данные из richtextbox в txt простым StreamWriter'ом, когда записываешь, получается все в одну строку - как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1):

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile("D:/file.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант

```
File.WriteAllLines("D:/file.txt", richTextBox1.Lines);
```